# Sending and Receiving data to pubnub website

Tags: javascript, pubnub

How to send database data to pubnub and how to receive data from pubnub   website for live data streaming

[image]

Its not clearly.

Comment: May you post the text itself, rather than text within an image?

Comment: please send me text with image.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the actual question is here but I'll attempt to address it.

PubNub is not really a website, it's a realtime network service with [*serverless* Functions that can process the messages](https://www.pubnub.com/products/functions/) that are published through that network.

You send data to the PubNub using the publish or fire API. You receive data using the subscribe API. You just need to pick a [PubNub SDK (there's over 70 to choose from)](https://www.pubnub.com/docs) to implement your app using these APIs. Here's the [JavaScript SDK for example](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk). Put Functions aside for now and concentrate on the publish/subscribe part first.

Also, you might want to review [How PubNub Works](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tech/how-pubnub-works/) docs to understand what PubNub is (and is not) and what it can do for your applications you use it in.